# Solve $9\cosh(x) - 5\sinh(x) = 9$

Tags: hyperbolic-functions

I am having trouble solving $$9\cosh(x)-5\sinh(x)=9$$

I have done these steps already:
$$9\left(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}\right) - 5\left(\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}\right)=9$$
$$\frac{9e^x +9e^{-x}-5e^x+5e^{-x}}{2} =9 $$
$$2e^x + 7e^{-x} = 9$$

I am stuck on where to go next. (Provided the steps i've taken before are correct)

Thanks

Comment: Let $y=e^{x}$ and solve for $y$ first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: multiply your equation by $$e^x$$ and solve a quadratic equation
the equation is given by $$2e^{2x}-9e^x+7=0$$ can you finish this?

Comment: So simple yet I couldn't see it. Thank you

Comment: you are welcome, some simple Things we can not see in the world

Answer (score 1):

Take $e^{x}=p$.

Then your equation becomes
$$2p+\frac{7}{p}=9$$
$$2p^2-9p+7=0$$
$$p=\frac{9\pm\sqrt{81-56}}{4}=\frac{9\pm5}{4}=1,\frac{14}{4}$$
$$x=\ln \left(\frac{9\pm5}{4}\right)=0,\ln \frac{14}{4}$$

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Funny, I thought $p=1$ ($x=0$) was a solution...

Answer (score 0):

Hint : multiply by  $y=e^x$ and solve the equation with  $y$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Your equation is:
$$
\frac{2e^{2x}-9e^x+7}{e^x}=0
$$
solve for $e^x=y$